# Email FTP - Tracking file data delivery

Tags: marketing-cloud, java, ftp

We are using FTP mechanism for mass email sending out i.e. we send file contianing list of the email Ids to whom email to be sent, email template to be used, dynamic data points.

What is the mechanism for verifying
a. tracking FTP file delivery 
b. tracking individual email of FTP file
through API.

Regards,
Ganga

Answer (score 0):

You can't use FTP natively from Apex as you only have HTTP connections - See Wikipedias [Protocol overview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol#Protocol_overview).

So you will need to wrap it with an external service that is capable of working with the protocol and then work directly with that service.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for response. Technologies involved I did not mention, apologies. It is from Java to Exact Target Email Service.